# How to detect USB devices in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-usb

I'm currently creating an application that aims to automatically move a file between the folder of a USB device and an internal folder.

I have the code that moves the files between two folders working on an emulator, however I cannot configure the code to work on a live machine as when I connect my device to Android Studio the Device File Explorer fails to display the USB device.

I have the USB device connected to my Android Device and my Android Device is connected to Android Studio over Wi-Fi.

(I am aware that interaction with files on a USB device will void my app from ever getting on the app store, this is purely a non-commercial, internal app)

Comment: Can you provide some code snippet or the error that you are facing??

Comment: @TanishqChawda There is no code, I am physically plugging a USB stick into my device  that is wi-fi connected to my computer and it is not showing up in the Android Studio File Explorer

Comment: Are you using Wireless debugging android ?

Comment: @TanishqChawda yes

Comment: do you want to open Device File explorer?? of your device that you have connected to wifi

Comment: @TanishqChawda I have an external hard drive plugged into my tablet and my tablet is connected to my computer via wireless debugging. I want to see the contents of my external hard drive on my computer via Android Studios File Explorer

Comment: @TanishqChawda I cannot, or I would not have asked the question? My Device File Explorer shows the same files, regardless of if the USB stick is plugged in or not